# netTiers causes FatalExecutionEngineError in WPF

Tags: wpf, .nettiers

I created a brand new WpfApplication, referenced netTiers classes, stuck a DataGrid on MainWindow, and set DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataRepository.SomeViewProvider.GetAll().

This causes the returned VList to be successfully bound and displayed.  After i run the program, clicking one of the datagrid headers orders by that column.

The problem occurs on the second click of any column header.  The program crashes and throws a FatalExecutionEngineError at VList.InsertItem.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, or give me some pointers as to how I can debug this error?

Comment: Do you have any sample code? A little hard to tell from this..

Comment: dataGrid1.ItemsSource = DataRepository.SomeViewProvider.GetById(35); - this is literally all the code i've added to the WPF.  The problem is related to netTiers generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance you could contact [CodeSmith Support](http://www.codesmithtools.com/contactus) with a sample and we will take a look into this issue. As a side note, I know that there was a set of Microsoft Patches that fixed this Fatal Execution Error for VS2008.

[Fatal Execution Error in W3WP with .NET 3.5 SP1 - crash in the loader](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981574/)

[An update for the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/959209)

Thanks
-[Blake Niemyjski](http://www.codesmithtools.com/)

Comment: i'll look into creating a repro package and send it through.  It seems those updates are not relevant to this case; i'm using win7 x64 and vs2010

Comment: have created this repro package and contact codesmith support

Comment: Thanks I see your email and will communicate with you via support.